# Is toLocaleString() supported on Apple devices?

Tags: jquery, ios, safari

I have this code that inserts a comma every 4 digets (en locale), it seems to work perfectly on Chrome, IE and Android but not on an iPad. Is there an easy way around this?

[This page](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) at w3schools says that it is supported by Safari, but my code doesn't seem to work.

**HTML**

```
<input id="value" name="value" type="text">
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#value').on('keyup', function (e) {
    $(this).val(Number($(this).val().replace(/,/g, "")).toLocaleString());
})
```